# Beautifulsoup Scraping Object Selection

Tags: beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape by Beautifulsoup and new to this, I need table rows as you see [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0mTPv.jpg).
The tables are coming from reactapp and then shown on the website. I need suggestion how to do this. I am struggling to create the beautifulsoup object and do not know what the actual class to grap to reach table rows and their content.

```
webpage = urlopen(req).read()
soup = bs(webpage, "html.parser")
table=soup.find('table', {'class': 'equity'})
rows=list()
for row in table.findAll("tr"):
     rows.append(row)
```

Need your help, really appreciated, having hard time to get it done!

Answer (score 0):

You can grab the `td` elements with this code:

```
webpage = urlopen(req).read()
soup = bs(webpage, "lxml")
table=soup.find('table', {'class': 'table'}).find('tr')
rows=list()
for row in table.findAll("td"):
     rows.append(row)
```

I prefered using `lxml` as the parser because it has some advantages, but you can keep using `html.parser`

You can also use `pandas`, It will create, It's so much easier to learn from its documentaion (there is a lot).